# How would I calculate the weighted average including two different variables? (Categorical scoring)

Tags: average

Apologies if this is fairly straight forward. I'm looking to obtain a weighted average for categorical scores in a table based on two variables: 1) the number of users, 2) the number of transactions.

So as an example:

| category | score | number_of_users | number_of_transactions |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 4 | 25000 | 478 |
| B | 7 | 768 | 878 |
| C | 9 | 100 | 90 |
| D | 6 | 19000 | 208 |

If I wanted to obtain the weighted average based on number of users, it would be:

(4 x 25000) + (7 x 768) + (9 x 100) + (6 x 19000) = 220,276 /
25000 + 768 + 100 + 19000 = 44,868

220,276 / 44,868 = 4.90

However, how would I go about finding a weighted average that incorporates number of users and number of transactions? Ideally I'd like the transactions to have a greater bearing- E.G. in the table above, Category B's score would be more important than Category A's score due to the higher number of transactions.

Comment: "Category B's score would be more important than Category A's score" : How much more important, mathematically?

Comment: Let's say for this case that number of users would be 0.4 and number of transactions would be 0.6

Comment: Take the weighted average, based solely on the number of users.  Denote this as $U$.  Take the weighted average based solely on the number of transactions.  Denote this as $T$.  Before you can combine the two, you need a way of relating users to transactions.  If you assume that $6$ users are as important as $4$ transactions, then you could simply take $(0.6)T + (0.4)U$.  However, this analysis is incomplete.  ...see next comment

Comment: Suppose that you alter the scenario, where the weighted average of transactions is still $1.5$ times as important as the weighted average of users, but that you expect each user to create $8$ transactions.  Then, before you compared $U$ and $T$, you would have to *normalize* $T$ to $T' = \frac{T}{8}$.  Not a simple issue.

Comment: Thanks for the information, it's given be a good basis to work from.